# PHP-FPM consume all the CPU even there's no request

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I got a very weird problem. My wordpress previously was working fine but recently and suddenly it turned very slow and the nginx returns 502 bad gateway sometimes. So I did some investigation, then I noticed the PHP-FPM processes consume all the CPU **even there's no request**. Everytime I restarted the wordpress the idle CPU usage just jumped to 0% instantly, and I can see several PHP-FPM processes were working with high CPU consumption, and the MySQL process consumed a lot CPU resource too, no matter if there is a request.

1. I tried to stop all the plugins - didn't work, same symptom.
2. I tried to update the wordpress to the latest version but DIDN't
   connect to database - CPU usage is normal.
3. I tried to update the wordpress to the latest version and only keep the file wp-config.php (database username + pwd) - didn't work, same symptom.

This is so weird but seems it's related to the mysql database? But why?

Thanks in advance.

```
top - 02:08:12 up 56 min,  1 user,  load average: 10.18, 9.41, 8.68
Tasks: 115 total,  11 running, 104 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 36.6%us, 10.4%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si, 53.0%st
Mem:    766112k total,   682116k used,    83996k free,   239696k buffers
Swap:  1572860k total,     2664k used,  1570196k free,   125412k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                          
23854 www       20   0 59952  30m 4688 R 44.5  4.1   3:56.99 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24337 www       20   0 60204  32m 4520 R 44.2  4.3   3:53.83 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24300 www       20   0 52004  23m 4448 R 42.9  3.2   3:48.47 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24287 www       20   0 54324  27m 5140 R 37.6  3.7   3:54.34 php-fpm                                                                                                           
23855 www       20   0 54824  26m 4504 R 35.6  3.5   3:57.25 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24323 www       20   0 46108  19m 4856 R 35.6  2.6   3:57.73 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24274 www       20   0 56356  28m 4548 R 35.2  3.9   3:56.55 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24374 www       20   0 55080  26m 4524 R 33.9  3.5   3:52.03 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24385 www       20   0 63820  33m 4428 R 33.2  4.5   3:51.53 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24394 www       20   0 57900  29m 4444 R 30.6  3.9   3:50.09 php-fpm                                                                                                           
24250 mysql     20   0  214m  29m 5860 S 23.9  3.9   1:35.21 mysqld                                                                                                            
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  1.7  0.0   0:01.31 watchdog/0                                                                                                        
  216 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  1.0  0.0   0:02.96 kjournald                                                                                                         
23850 www       20   0 18624  11m  868 S  0.3  1.6   0:01.89 nginx                                                                                                             
23851 www       20   0 18812  12m  876 S  0.3  1.6   0:03.61 nginx                                                                                                             
27889 root      20   0  2712 1136  880 R  0.3  0.1   0:00.81 top
```

Comment: When you say there is no request, do you mean http requests? Maybe some background tasks?
Did you try a fresh and empty install of wordpress (not a migration)? Your site could be corrupted.

Comment: Restart the WordPress? What did you mean here? Better looking to access.log for more information.

Comment: @fiber-optic and @ anh-tuan , there is no request, I shut down the Nginx so it's confirmed no requests came in, and from the access log I knew it too. Yes I tried to restart the wordpress but it didn't help. It's possible to have some background tasks but is there a way to know it?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it's caused by an XML RPC attack. It's resolved now.

For more information:
https://medium.com/@tturnbull/throttle-xmlrpc-php-attacks-on-wordpress-with-nginx-3cc4a12b7f76